# Entry Widget python 3.x ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, tkinter

i am currently doing my activity in class about user interface in python 3.x. I used tkinter and wanted to get a integer from a Entry Widget. I searched and tried solutions from other questions from this site and non of them actually helped me yet. I made a code with the same function but without interface and it worked just fine but after i tried to convert it into interfaced one, i then got stuck whit this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Klien\Desktop\w.py", line 40, in deposit
    x = int(E2.get())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

import sys
class User():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, gender, age, pin, secretQuestion):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.gender = gender
        self.age = age
        self.pin = pin
        self.secretQuestion = secretQuestion
        self.balance = 0

    def menu(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        label1 = Label(window, text="Choose Options")
        label1.pack()
        a = Button(window,text="1. Personal Information",command=person1.personalInfo)
        a.pack()
        b = Button(window,text="2. Deposit",command=person1.deposit)
        b.pack()
        c = Button(window,text="3. Withdraw",command=person1.withdraw)
        c.pack()
        d = Button(window,text="4. Change PIN",command=person1.changePin)
        d.pack()
        e = Button(window,text="5. Quit",command=person1.logout)
        e.pack()

    def deposit(self):
        window = tk.Toplevel(root)
        L2 = Label(window,text='Input money to be deposited:')
        L2.pack()

        E2= Entry(window,bd=1)
        E2.pack()
        a = Button(window,text='okay',command=E2.get())
        a.pack()

        x = int(E2.get())

        if x > 0:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success","Deposit Success")
            self.balance += x
        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please Input again.")

        def withdraw(self):
        x = int(input("Input money to withdraw: "))
        if x > self.balance:
                print("Insufficient balance!")
        if x < self.balance:
                self.balance -= x
                print("Withdraw Success!")

    def logout(self):
        root.destroy()

    def personalInfo(self):
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Personal Info","Full Name: "+self.first_name.title()+" "+self.last_name.title()+'\n Gender:'+self.gender.title()+'\n Age:'+(str(self.age))+'\nBalance:'+(str(self.balance)))

    def changePin(self):
        y = str(input("What is the name of your dog?"))
        if y == self.secretQuestion:
            z = str(input("Enter new PIN"))
            self.pin = z
            print("Successful!")

person1 = User('klien menard','luminarias','male','12','123123','k',)
z = person1.pin

def log():
    y = E1.get()
    if y == z:
        person1.menu()


    if y != z:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error","Incorrect PIN")
root = tk.Tk()


L1 = Label(root,text='PIN')
L1.pack()


E1= Entry(root,bd=1)
E1.pack()
b = Button(root,text='okay',command=log)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

part of the code with error:

```
def deposit(self):
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    L2 = Label(window,text='Input money to be deposited:')
    L2.pack()

    E2= Entry(window,bd=1)
    E2.pack()
    a = Button(window,text='okay',command=E2.get())
    a.pack()

    x = int(E2.get())

    if x > 0:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Success","Deposit Success")
        self.balance += x
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo("Error","Please Input again.")
```

Im new to this python thing and dont really have good programming skills.

Comment: `E2.get()` is returning an empty string.

Comment: E2 does not exist outside of the function deposit().  Use an instance object, self.E2 so it is usable throughout the class, and command= points to a function that will store_the_return_in_a_variable=self.E2.get().  See the callback() function at  http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: thanks CurlyJoe and Barmar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are trying to make the conversion to int before E2.get() returns any valid value, so your E2.get() return '' instead of something you can convert to int and Python complains. I think you have to separate the E2 creation and the x assignment and make E2 accessible from module level. BTW, improve naming...

Comment: Thanks, this worked the same way with the @Curly Joe's solution.